# What does Invoke a System Command means in R?

Tags: r

I have following code to execute but I found that `system(eval` is working behind the scene. I want to know what does it do ? I have found one resource but it does not explain in detail!

```
cmd.command.line.input <- "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH C:\Users\myusername\Documents\R\Send_Outlook_Email.R"
system(eval(cmd.command.line.input),intern=F,show.output.on.console = T,invisible=F)
```

R to execute but could not understand what does `system(eval` do ?

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember you can always `help(cmd)` in R to tell what a command does. for example, `help(eval)` contains:

> Evaluate an R expression in a specified environment.

and much more information. In your case, you are just passing it a string and no other arguments, so it evaluates the string in your current scope (just like typing `"mystring"` including the quotes in the shell) and returning it. As such, is seems redundant here, since you could have just used `cmd.command.line.input` directly and git rid of `eval`.

The title for `help(system)` is

> ‘system’ invokes the OS command specified by ‘command’.

In your case OS is Windows, so you are telling Windows directly to run

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH C:\Users\myusername\Documents\R\Send_Outlook_Email.R
```

Windows will run this command as if your were in a Windows CMD and typed the command directly.